# Check if the input data is already exists in the DB jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that adds device name and device id in mysql database. I have written a jquery script that will check whether the device id is already in the db. If exists it will return false. I have the following code-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
                                        $('#Submit').click(function() {alert('in');
                                            var checkID = $('#device_id').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
                                            $.post('includes/checkid.php', {'device_id' : checkID}, function(data) {
                                                if(data=='exist') alert("already exists"); return false;
                                                else $('#add_dev').submit();
                                            });
                                        });});
                                        </script>


<form method="post" action="includes/process_add.php" name = "add_dev" id = "add_dev">
                    <tr><td width="150">Device ID</td><td>:<input type="text" name="device_id" id= "device_id"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Device Name</td><td>:<input type="text" name="device_name"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><br><input type="submit" name="submit" id= "submit" value="Add device"></td></tr>
                    </form>
```

and checkid.php is -

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$id = $_POST['device_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT device_id FROM devices WHERE device_id = '$id'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    echo "exist";
}else echo 'notexist';
?>
```

its not working..

Comment: $.post is async, you can't return value from success callback. BTW, your if/else syntax is wrong here

Comment: _its not working_ is not a good description for any problem. Please debug information.

Comment: i have added braces after if. still adding the duplicated.

Comment: @user3001326 still, $.post is async, the form will submit before waiting any ajax request response

Comment: what should i do to make it sync?

Comment: @user3001326 don't make it sync, just try... (answer comming)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is async, return false outside ajax success callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //newly added 
    $('#submit').click(function () {        
        alert('in');
        var checkID = $('#device_id').val(); // assuming this is a input text field
        $.post('includes/checkid.php', {
            'device_id': checkID
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'exist') alert("already exists");            
            else $('#add_dev').submit();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Should be `$('#submit')` not `$('#Submit')`, try that

Comment: now after hitting submit button it is doing nothing. Also if i input some unique value :/

Comment: Are you sure the success callback of $.post method is reached? No PHP script error?

Comment: ya, i am sure about that. i have checked the checkid.php file separately .

Comment: No submit handler attached to form using jquery? Maybe try: `$('#add_dev').get(0).submit();` And check that the else statement is reached when expected

Comment: And the else statment is reached or not? (replace `$('#add_dev').submit();` with an `alert()` to check) No error in console???

Comment: So your ajax request is send or not? I'm sorry but you really don't give enough details in order to get some accurate help. `Nothing happen`? Even the `alert('in')`??????

Comment: even it does not show alert('in') also not reaching to the form submitting.

Comment: It should show the alert('in'), you are still doing something wrong somewhere else...   see: http://jsfiddle.net/NxLGC/  I cannot help you more without knowing what you are doing...

Comment: now its showing alert('in'), and i guess i is submitting the form before entering into the javascript function.

Comment: Funny enough, now the alert() is shown and still you don't tell what change you did to make it work. I cannot devine what you are doing wrong... Sorry but GL

Comment: nothing actually, but restarted the server and cleared the cache.